# What does dd do that pv doesn't?

Tags: linux, command-line, dd, disk-image

I see examples online all the time of using `dd` in combination with `pv` to show progress... But, something I don't understand is that `pv` is perfectly capable of doing the task entirely on it's own. So, why use `dd` as well? Is there some advantage `dd` provides that `pv` doesn't?

Examples using both `dd` and `pv`. Some of these are really complicated...

```
dd if=/dev/sda | pv | dd of=/mnt/backup.img
dd if=/dev/sda | pv -s 10G | dd of=/mnt/backup.img
dd if=/dev/sda | (pv -s `fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep -o '[0-9]*\{1\} MB' | awk '{print $1}'`m) | dd of=/mnt/backup.img
```

You can acheive the same thing using `pv` alone by doing

```
pv /dev/sda > /mnt/backup.img
```

Comment: "Some of these are really complicated" - Seems like a good enough reason to just use pv.  I searched on the topic, most results, seem to indicate there isn't a built in way to report the progress.  So either dd has added this feature since those statements were made.  But [pv](http://www.kossboss.com/dd-progress-dd-progress-with-pv) also seems to communicate between two processes.

Comment: can't find a soure, but I'm pretty sure pv stands for Pipe-View, since it just seems to show statistical data on piping/redirecting operations. In fact, I'm certian that the pv command listed would work in exactly the same way without the pv invocation, other than that you wouldn't get the nice progress output.

Comment: I didn't like the title @barlop made since I know what `pv` is doing, I just don't understand what `dd` is doing that `pv` isn't. So, I changed the title to "what does dd do that pv doesn't?"

Comment: @Ramhound, but in my example, `pv /dev/sda > /mnt/backup.img`, `pv` is not reading from a pipe? It's reading from the device file.

Comment: @druciferre - Your other three examples do pipe the stdout. Its been awhile, and I forget what function `>` performs but I do know the results in communication between two processes.

Comment: > is output redirection. same as piping but to a file instead of a subsequent process. the PV does nothing more than cat the file, and  count bytes and give you a progress bar. its the > in that command thats actually moving data.

Comment: @druciferre: You should take a look at this related interesting question: [Is dd better than cat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150697/is-dd-better-than-cat)

Comment: @FrankThomas - Redirect, i knew it was something, had to write my own limited kernel with pipe and redirect support was never able to get both working :$

Comment: @FrankThomas pv is indeed 'pipe viewer'

Comment: @Karan +1 that is a fantastic link. I would note that many have pointed out a difference between cat and dd being that dd you can configure block size. Though pv can also.  One of the answers there shows a way to monitor block size with the ltrace command. You can specify block size with e.g. `pv -s 2M`

Comment: yes your new title "What does dd do that pv doesn't?" is much better than any prior one.

Comment: This is a brilliant question and the current answer to it seems to be incorrect. It deserves a better, more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) just provides sight into a pipe operation, so the real question is, is the pipe/redirection equivalent to [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29). the answer of course is no.

While simple cases of `dd` usage may appear to work similarly to IO redirection or piping, `dd` is a rather complicated tool with a lot of features related to file data conversion (piping barely knows what a file is, let alone what kind of byte order/encoding it is) whereas redirection just pushes bits, and `pv` just watches data going through a pipe, with no more understanding of it than just counting bytes.

`dd` understands disk structures like blocks and addresses, which `pv` has no knowledge of. `dd` interfaces with the kernel at the driver level, while `pv` occurs above a great deal of IO abstraction.

for instance, `dd` could grab the backup of the MBR of a disk (always in the 63rd block) with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=MBR_boot.img bs=512 count=1 skip=62
```

There is no clean way to do that with redirection/piping.

Comment: What happens if `pv` runs into an error while reading? I know what happens when you use `dd`. It stops... Also, it should be `pv` does have a flag to specify how many bytes to read. so you could backup the first 512 bytes, but you wouldn't be able to skip the first 62.

Comment: I just did man pv, and it has stuff about blocks

Comment: @druciferre what i'm going to say doesn't answer what you said but may be of interest to you.  ddrescue is very good it reports progress nicely

Comment: check karan's link showing an answer on differences between dd and cat, Its main point is you can't specify block size in cat. Thing is, you can in pv. One answer suggests the ltrace  command to monitor block size e.g. you can see dd famously defaulting to 512 bytes.  Doing this in ubuntu `$ ltrace pv  </dev/zero >/dev/null`  shows pv using 128KB block size. You can say  pv -s 2M  and then it uses 2MB  So pv totally lets you specify block size and it's in man pv.